# Minimizing application with qt

Tags: linux, qt, minimize

I created (in Qt5 under Linux) a small QMainWindow app.

I noticed that when I'm clicking on the minimizing button, I cannot see  my app anymore. In other term, I cannot see it in the bar !?

I tried with docky, cairo-dock and native Mint bar and... nothing work !)

Any idea ?

Answer (score 1):

Is this running it in the debug mode inside of Qt Creator?  Maybe you have to deploy it and run it outside of Qt Creator for it to get its own button on the dock/taskbar.

If not, you might have a bug that should be reported to qt.